# Oledb Datareader can't read excel cell data of 656 characters

Tags: vb.net

i have been trying to read excel using oledb data reader,everything  is ok but i have problem reading one excel column content which has cell data of more than 600 characters. oledb datareader gives empty string after read operation.but when i tried to shorten that cell data it successfully read the data. Any fix for this problem?
Thanks.